# Migrating from Google+ Sign-in to Google Sign-in

Tags: google-api-php-client

I just got an email today stating that the Google+ Sign-in API is being shut down in March 2019. Is there a way to use the existing PHP library to migrate to the newer Google Sign-in?  All the migration documentation seems to be for JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac : Can you try out the second answer posted for the solution and provide me your valuable feedback?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56770593/3679976

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to get this migration to be done using PHP and found an article for the same but I am not 100% sure about this. I am going to describe the scenario below please confirm me if it helps:

[image]

Referred Links:

**Link 1**- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in

**Link 2**- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#plusv1

Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs
Google APIs use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and authorization. Google supports common OAuth 2.0 scenarios such as those for web server, installed, and client-side applications.

So as per my findings if we are using oauth2 authetication for Google API we can access google sign and google+ api by only changing the scope in the API calls.

```
For Google Sign In, please see **Link 1** above.
For Google+ API, please see **Link 2** above.
```

I had also created a test script for the same please see below:

**user_authentication.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

//Google API PHP Library includes
require_once 'dbcontroller.php';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Fill CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET ID, REDIRECT URI from Google Developer Console
$client_id = 'XXXXXX';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXX';
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/googleplus/user_authentication.php';
$simple_api_key = 'XXXXXXXX';

//Create Client Request to access Google API
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("PHP Google OAuth Login Example");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setDeveloperKey($simple_api_key);
$client->addScope(array('openid', 'email', 'profile'));
//$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
//$client->addScope(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));

//Send Client Request
$objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

//Logout
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $client->revokeToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); //redirect user back to page
}

//Authenticate code from Google OAuth Flow
//Add Access Token to Session
if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

//Set Access Token to make Request
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

//Get User Data from Google Plus
//If New, Insert to Database
if ($client->getAccessToken())
{
    $userData = $objOAuthService->userinfo->get();
    if (!empty($userData))
    {
        $objDBController = new DBController();
        $conn = ($objDBController->_conn);

        $existing_member = $objDBController->getUserByOAuthId($conn, $userData->id);
        if (empty($existing_member))
        {
            $objDBController->insertOAuthUser($conn, $userData);
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
else
{
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
require_once("viewlogin.php")
?>
```

> **Note:** Please replace your google client ID, client secret and API key

**viewlogin.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .box {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;background-color: #F1F1F1;border:0;width:340px;webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);margin: 0 auto 25px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0px;}
            .box img{padding: 10px 0px;}
            .box a{color: #427fed;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none;}
            .heading {text-align:center;padding:10px;font-family: 'Open Sans', arial;color: #555;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 400;}
            .circle-image{width:100px;height:100px;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 50%;}
            .welcome{font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;margin: 10px 0 0;min-height: 1em;}
            .oauthemail{font-size: 14px;}
            .logout{font-size: 13px;text-align: right;padding: 5px;margin: 20px 5px 0px 5px;border-top: #CCCCCC 1px solid;}
            .logout a{color:#8E009C;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="heading">PHP Google OAuth 2.0 Login</div>
        <div class="box">
            <div>
                <!-- Show Login if the OAuth Request URL is set -->
                <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
                    <img src="images/user.png" width="100px" size="100px" /><br/>
                    <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Sign In with Google</a>
                    <!-- Show User Profile otherwise-->
                <?php else: ?>
                    <img class="circle-image" src="<?php echo $userData["picture"]; ?>" width="100px" size="100px" /><br/>
                    <p class="welcome">Welcome <a href="<?php echo $userData["link"]; ?>" /><?php echo $userData["name"]; ?></a>.</p>
                    <p class="oauthemail"><?php echo $userData["email"]; ?></p>
                    <div class='logout'><a href='?logout'>Logout</a></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dbcontroller.php**

```
<?php

class DBController
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "root";
    private $database = "test";
    public $_conn = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if (!empty($conn))
        {
            $this->_conn = $conn;
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->_conn);
    }

    function connectDB()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn)
    {
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $this->database);
    }

    function getUserByOAuthId($conn, $oauth_user_id)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE oauth_user_id = '" . $oauth_user_id . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (!empty($result))
        {
            $existing_member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $existing_member;
        }
    }

    function insertOAuthUser($conn, $userData)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO members (member_name, member_email, oauth_user_id, oauth_user_page, oauth_user_photo) VALUES ('" . $userData->name . "','" . $userData->email . "','" . $userData->id . "','" . $userData->link . "','" . $userData->picture . "')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }

}

?>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "google/apiclient",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Client library for Google APIs",
    "keywords": ["google"],
    "homepage": "http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "google/auth": "^1.0",
        "google/apiclient-services": "~0.13",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "~2.0||~3.0||~4.0||~5.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~0.3.10||~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3.1||~6.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8.36",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.1",
        "cache/filesystem-adapter": "^0.3.2"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "cache/filesystem-adapter": "For caching certs and tokens (using Google_Client::setCache)"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Google_": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/Google/Service/"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

> You can download google client library from github:
>   https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
>
> and can get the vendor stuff using composer.json

For your table "members" the table structure will be as shown in below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using below approach to migrate from Google+ Sign In to Google Sign In:

**Step 1:** Identify Google+ API endpoints and find equivalent Google API endpoint.

**Step 2:** Generally used Google+ API endpoint is the '/me' endpoint that returns the user information:
https://www.googleapis.com//plus/v1/people/me

**Step 3:** Replace the old Google+ API endpoint with new Google API endpoint.

The new endpoint is:
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses,occupations,organizations,addresses

> You can test all the fields that can be passed to retrieve various
>   other information of the user using below link:
>   https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

You can take reference from below code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('settings.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            #login-button {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 50px 0;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <a id="login-button" href="<?php echo 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=online' ?>">
            Login with Google
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.php**

```
<?php

$clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //Google client ID
$clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //Google client secret
$redirectURL = 'http://localhost/login-with-google/gauth.php'; //Callback URL

/* Google App Client Id */
define('CLIENT_ID', $clientId);

/* Google App Client Secret */
define('CLIENT_SECRET', $clientSecret);

/* Google App Redirect Url */
define('CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', $redirectURL);
?>
```

**google-login-api.php**

```
<?php

class GoogleLoginApi
{

    public function GetAccessToken($client_id, $redirect_uri, $client_secret, $code)
    {
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
        $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code=' . $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($http_code != 200)
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receieve access token');

        return $data;
    }

    public function GetUserProfileInfo($access_token)
    {
        $url = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses,photos,genders';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($http_code != 200)
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to get user information');

        return $data;
    }

}

?>
```

**gauth.php**

```
<?php
require_once('settings.php');
require_once('google-login-api.php');

// Google passes a parameter 'code' in the Redirect Url
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    try {
        $gapi = new GoogleLoginApi();
        // Get the access token 
        $data = $gapi->GetAccessToken(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL, CLIENT_SECRET, $_GET['code']);
        // Get user information
        $user_info = $gapi->GetUserProfileInfo($data['access_token']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #information-container {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        }

        .information {
            margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        }

        .information label {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 150px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .information span {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .information img {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 100px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="information-container">
        <div class="information">
            <label>Name</label><span><?php echo $user_info['names'][0]['displayName'] ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <label>Email</label><span><?php echo $user_info['emailAddresses'][0]['value'] ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <label>Picture</label><img src="<?php echo $user_info['photos'][0]['url'] ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Feedbacks appreciated.
Thank You :)